# RxJava Completable onErrorComplete+merge doesnt work

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to merge two `Completable`-s but there is no final `onComplete` call.

This is my code:

```
private fun dataLoading(): Completable {
    return Completable.merge(listOf(
            method1(),
            method2()))
            .doOnComplete {
                // not called
            }
}

private fun method1(): Completable {
    return merge(loadHistory(),
            loadData(),
            loadFavorites(),
            loadBalance())
            .doOnComplete {
                // called
            }
}

private fun method2(): Completable {
    return Single
            .fromFuture(locationSubject.toFuture()) // BehaviorSubject
            .timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // waiting for coordinates 1 sec
            .flatMapCompletable { onLocationLoaded(it) } // not called
            .onErrorComplete() // got TimeoutException here
            .doOnComplete {
                // called
            }
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert between Single and Subject via to/fromFuture? `toFuture` requires the source to complete. Use `locationSubject.firstOrError().timeout().flatMapCompletable...` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(from the comments:)

`toFuture` requires the source to complete. Use something like this:

```
private fun method2(): Completable {
    return locationSubject  // BehaviorSubject
        .firstOrError() // <---------------------------------------------- Single
        .timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // waiting for coordinates 1 sec
        .flatMapCompletable { onLocationLoaded(it) } // not called
        .onErrorComplete() // got TimeoutException here
        .doOnComplete {
            // called
        }
}
```